# Damped Oscillation & Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

- Question posed:

---

"Particle undergoing damped oscillation by the DE:

**x'' + 4x' + 8x = 0**

Calculate its displacement **x(t)** if in addition the initial conditions x(0) = 0 and ˙x(0) = 4 are satisfied."

---

- I have obtained the equation: 
  [image]
- How do I calculate the displacement now I have this equation?

Thanks

Comment: Please describe your background -- that is, if you expect any other answer than the suggestion to check the first chapter of your notes on the subject.

Comment: Substitute $$x(t)=e^{\lambda t}$$

Comment: Its a mechanics module in a mathematics degree, I have no background in physics and the notes are not useful, hence I am using stack exchange.

Comment: Using x(t), is that saying x'' is a function of t?

Comment: I have obtained an equation, see above question, is this correct?

Comment: What do you think $x$ measures?

Answer (score 2):

For homogeneous equation we generally start by assuming general solution  with $x=e^{mt} $ . From here we obtain auxilliary equation by putting values of $x'',x',x $  which is $m^2+4m+8=0$ so $m=-2\pm 2i $ so the general solution is $e^{-2t}(a\cos (2t)+b\sin (2t) ) $ a,b are constants.  This is obtained using $x=ae^{(-2+2i)t}+be^{(-2-2i)t} $ and some help from Euler formula . Generally three cases for m arise but since you are having more physics background I am not posting it.However if you need it leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have obtained my equation x(t). How do I now calculate the displacement of this particle?

Comment: Just use the given conditions and find a and b.